# Why Bender used 'they' for 'cigars'?

Tags: word-usage

> *[Bender explains why he drinks so much]*
>   *Bender:* Nah, I'm trying to watch my input. I need plenty of wholesome nutritious alcohol. The chemical energy keeps my fuel cells charged.
>   *Fry:* What are the cigars for?
>   *Bender:* **They** make me look cool.

Why he use *"They"* but not *"Its"*?
Is it a mistake?

In addition:

> *Leela:* "What if I just help the two of you find a bigger apartment?"
>  
>   *Bender:* "I don't know...I've got a lot of great memories of my old place." *[pushes button]*
>   *Bender:* "And now **they**'re gone!"

And why does he use *"they*" for *"memories"*?

Comment: Isn't "cigar" a countable noun?

Comment: "cigar" is the countable noun. But "They" for he or see or for life nouns.

Comment: A quick trip to the dictionary would show this is proper usage. From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/they): **they** (*pronoun*) _used for referring to a group of people or **things** that have already been mentioned or that are already known about_; from [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/they): **they** (*pronoun*) _used as the subject of a verb to refer to people, animals, or **things** already mentioned_. [_emphasis added_]

Comment: No, unlike "he" and "she", "they" is not for living things only---just like "it" is not for living things only! "Those are my pencils; give them to me!" "That is my pen; give it to me!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that your quotes are from *Futurama*, an animation that usually uses hilarious and witty words. Quite often, the words just mean something they do not normally mean. And, since I am not a big fan, though I did watch some episodes, I cannot recall such scenes.

Anyway, I believe that a straightforward interpretation could apply.

> *Fry:* What are the cigars for?
>   *Bender:* They make me look cool.

Why he use **They** but not **Its**? Is it a mistake?

No, it is not a mistake. In that Bender's line, the word *they* refers to *cigars*.
*Cigars* is plural, so we must use the pronoun **they**, not **its**.

The same goes to the use of *they* for *memories*.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. I thought what them for plural live-nouns and its for plural dead-nouns

Comment: I'm glad that I can help. The agreements for live-nouns and dead-nouns exist in Ukrainian language, am I right?

Comment: @Mediator, "Its" is the possessive for singular non-gendered things. "I'm taking my car to the shop because its brakes are going bad."

Answer (score 1):

The following simple table should help:

```
Inanimate pronouns/Third Person non-gender specific pronouns
            Singular    Plural
Subject        it        they
Object         it        them
Possessive     its       their
```

A possessive pronoun should be followed by a **noun**: *the cigar's **wrapper***, *its **wrapper***, *his **memories***. A regular pronoun may be followed by **verb**: *They **make**...*, *...they**'re**...* (*...they **are**...*), *it **does***, *it**'s*** (*it **is***, *it **has** [been]*). An exception is when the pronoun comes at the end of a phrase: *The cigars are Bender's*, *They are Bender's*, *The cigars are his*, *They are his*. So we know we are talking about *Bender's cigars*, *his cigars*. We can't say *Bender's them* or *Bender's they*, it would seem we are saying *Bender **is** them*, using the contracted form of *is*, which doesn't make sense. We can't even say *Bender's these* or *Bender's those*, we must explicitly state the noun (*cigars*).

*cigars* and *memories* are plural and not possessive. So the correct pronouns for both of them are *they* (subject) and *them* (object). *Bender's **memories**? What about **them**? **They**'re gone.*